# Get Wordpress User Info

Tags: php, wordpress

Good night guys,
I am not very familiar with Wordpress, but I am already completing my task, I can already send email, capture choice via jquery with Ajax processing email sending, but I can not capture the user logged in to Wordpress, I need a light.
Thankful,
Siro Souza

```
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=index.php">
<?php
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include ($location . '/wp-config.php');
include ($location . '/wp-load.php');
include ($location . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
global $current_user;
\\ retorna os dados do usuário logado
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
\\ passamos o ID do usuário e geramos o array
$user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
$first_name = $user_info->first_name;
$user_email = $user_info->user_email;
if(is_user_logged_in()){
$premium = $_POST['chosen_premium'];
$vnome = $first_name; 
$vemail_origem = $user_email;
$vassunto = "Prêmio Escolhido"; 
$vmensagem = $premium;
$msg="Nome: $vnome\n"; 
$msg.="Email: $vemail_origem\n"; 
$msg.="Assunto: $vassunto\n"; 
$msg.="Mensagem: $vmensagem\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inside your plugin or theme files you should be able to use somewhat similar code to the above...

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    echo '<pre>user_info: ' . print_r($user_info, true) . '</pre>';//debug
}
```

Are you trying to run this from outside of WordPress?  If you are still having issues, perhaps can you provide more details on what file you are using for your code?

Comment: I run php file in ajax, ie outside of Wordpress, then it would be impossible?

Comment: I would probably recommend using the built in WordPress AJAX functionality to keep things more consistent and WordPress-friendly. This article should be helpful to get you started using that method... https://benmarshall.me/wordpress-ajax-frontend-backend/

Comment: Many thanks for the article, the flow I follow is this:
Process a choice by getting String, sending this parameter in ajax processing PHP file, it processes data obtained from Jquery and sends send email, the detail is that, I can not get the user logged in. I've tried library include that manages just like this article explains: http://www.geoweb.blog.br/wordpress/wordpress-how-refresh-the-name-and-more-user-information-